# Python Cant Run or Reinstall Pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have a machine that has Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 installed. Normally to install packages under Python 3.4, I would run `pip3 install [PACKAGE]`.

But now when I run `pip3` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/volume1/@appstore/python3/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pip import pep425tags
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 335, in <module>
    supported_tags = get_supported()
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 307, in get_supported
    elif is_manylinux1_compatible():
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 163, in is_manylinux1_compatible
    return have_compatible_glibc(2, 5)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 187, in have_compatible_glibc
    version = [int(piece) for piece in version_str.split(".")]
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 187, in <listcomp>
    version = [int(piece) for piece in version_str.split(".")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20-2014'
```

Even if I download `get-pip.py` and run `python3 get-pip.py`, I get the same error.

What could the problem be?

Edit: Apparently this is a problem that is persistent on Synology installs when you installed DSM 6.0.

Comment: I think it means that the relatively new `pep425tags.py` is flawed...

Comment: What version of pip are you using?

Comment: what happens if you try `pip --python=python3 install -U pip` ?

Comment: `pip3 -V` returns the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I get same error, lol

Comment: you are getting this just if you type `pip3` or when installing a specific package?

Comment: see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3588

Comment: @BurhanKhalid the first line of the traceback is `from pip import main` which means the error happens *while importing / loading the pip module* so regardless of how it is used it will result in same error.

Comment: I think https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/3590#issuecomment-201108097 is the exact problem you are running into.

Comment: Yup! See my answer below for the code needed to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution courtesy of @Tadhg in the comments above.

[**Here**](https://reviewable.io/reviews/pypa/pip/3590) is a link to the necessary changes to `pep425tags.py`.

But here are the changes needed for all of you who are on this SO page.

Add the following function:

```
# Separated out from have_compatible_glibc for easier unit testing
def check_glibc_version(version_str, needed_major, needed_minor):
    # Parse string and check against requested version.
    #
    # We use a regexp instead of str.split because we want to discard any
    # random junk that might come after the minor version -- this might happen
    # in patched/forked versions of glibc (e.g. Linaro's version of glibc
    # uses version strings like "2.20-2014.11"). See gh-3588.
    m = re.match(r"(?P<major>[0-9]+)\.(?P<minor>[0-9]+)", version_str)
    if not m:
        warnings.warn("Expected glibc version with 2 components major.minor,"
                      " got: %s" % version_str, RuntimeWarning)
        return False
    return (int(m.group("major")) == needed_major and
            int(m.group("minor")) >= needed_minor)
```

and replace

```
# Parse string and check against requested version.
version = [int(piece) for piece in version_str.split(".")]
if len(version) < 2:
    warnings.warn("Expected glibc version with 2 components major.minor,"
                  " got: %s" % version_str, RuntimeWarning)
    return False
return version[0] == major and version[1] >= minimum_minor
```

with `return check_glibc_version(version_str, major, minimum_minor)`